# Backbone computed model

Tags: backbone.js

Please I have a challenge moving forward with this project (no server end). Consider this example:

```
var date = Date.now();
var item1 = new Item({date: date, title: 'breakfast', value: 100, history: false});
var item2 = new Item({date: date, title: 'lunch', value: 200, history: false});
var item3 = new Item({date: date, title: 'dinner', value: 300, history: false});

var items = new Backbone.Collection;
items.add(item1, item2, item3);

//Create a new model derived from these models and save in collection

var sum = 0;
items.each(function(elem) { 
    sum += parseInt(elem.get('value'));
    //elem.destroy();
}

var report = new Item({date: date, title: 'Report', value: sum, history: true});
items.add(report);
```

Works fine. 4 models will be displayed. But I don't want to keep these 3 models in the collection once report has been computed. The 3 models should be destroyed. When I refresh the page, only report model should display. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of adding the report model, use the [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) function: `items.reset(report)`

Comment: @Emile Thanks but this does not work. I want to create a report model using the value attr of these 3 models. The new model will be saved in the local storage and the 3 models will be destroyed. Subsequent refresh of the page should only display the report model. Note that I am using one collection for the report and models. One question is this: Can I do this using local storage? I am doubting

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the report model, use the [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) function: `items.reset(report)`